# Automorphic representations which are trivial at the archimedean place

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, automorphic-forms

Consider the Hilbert space $V = L^2(Z(\mathbb{A})\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})\backslash \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}))$. This is a unitary representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$, acting by right multiplication, so we can ask for the spectrum of unitary irreducible representations appearing in its decomposition.

$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ naturally embeds into $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$, and let us define $V_0$ to be the subspace of $V$ consisting of vectors fixed by $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. The action of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$ on $V$ preserves $V_0$.

**Question**: What is the decomposition of $V_0$ into irreducible representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$? In other words, what are the automorphic representations which are trivial representations of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

**Comment**: I couldn't easily find this question answered in the literature, because there the focus is on cuspidal representations, and the trivial representation of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not cuspidal. So the answer should somehow be encoded in the properties of the Eisenstein series, because in the classical theory the trivial representation = constant function, appears as a pole of the Eisenstein series.

Comment: If the local component at $\infty$ of an automorphic representation $\pi$ is one-dimensional, then $\pi$ is not generic, so it is one-dimensional and spanned by the automorphic form $\chi(\det g)$, where $\chi$ is a unitary Hecke character.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, thanks! So this implies that the only functions on $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A})$, which are left-$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ invariant, right-$\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ invariant, and $Z(\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}))$ invariant are constant?

Comment: If you want automorphic forms trivial at infinity, you should work with a group compact at infinity, e.g., quaternionic modular forms (on a definite quaternion algebra).

Comment: @PeterHumphries, How do I see explicitly that the space is one-dimensional? Naively, it sounds like it can’t be true: using the unique factorization of elements of $\mathrm{GL}_2(A)$, the space of such functions is basically the space of functions on $\prod_p K_p$ over the finite primes, so how can it be one-dimensional? (I’m probably missing something basic here.)

Comment: @Hedgehog that function won't be automorphic. More generally, you should look up the $L^2$-spectral decomposition for $L^2(\mathrm{GL}_2(F) \backslash \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}),\omega)$; see, for example, Section 2.6 of this paper: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00039-014-0277-4